# Can I ask question about Philosophy of Love/flirt here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

it sounds like a interesting topic and I got few questions in my mind that I would like to ask and increase my knowledge and understanding of flirt & just wonder if I can ask related question here ?

Comment: Philosophy of love? Sure! Flirtation/seduction tips? Probably a bit off topic...

Comment: The philosophy of *anything* is on topic, as long as it actually is philosophy... Best bet, ask and we'll help steer it on topic if it's a little questionable. :)